# Best way to Query a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dictionary

I have a dictionary, for example `Dictionary<int, string>`.
What would be the best way to get the string value if I know the key?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you know the key is in the dictionary:

```
value = dictionary[key];
```

If you're not sure:

```
dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

Comment: If you want to check the value you can quickly say something lie this 
`if(!dic.TryGetValue(key, out object o)  || o == null) return;`

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean by best?

This is the *standard* way to access `Dictionary` values by key:

```
var theValue = myDict[key];
```

If the key does not exist, this will throw an exception, so you may want to see if they key exists before getting it (not thread safe):

```
if(myDict.ContainsKey(key))
{
   var theValue = myDict[key];
}
```

Or, you can use `myDict.TryGetValue`, though this required the use of an out parameter in order to get the value.

Comment: myDict.TryGetValue is more efficient as it only needs to calculate the key once, unlike Contains followed by an indexre which does it twice.

Comment: @Martin: I bet that operation of key lookup is `O(1)`, so don't need to worry about. Anyway, +1

Comment: @Martin, however, it does require an `out` parameter that needs to be declared beforehand.

Comment: @zerkms, key lookup might be O(1) but that still adds up. Also GetHashCode might be O(anything) since that's implemented in the class of key.

Comment: @Oded Personally I would have an extension method on dictionaries which is GetValueOrDefault(key) which internally uses TryGetValue and returns the default of value if no such item is present.

Comment: @Martin - sounds like a nice little extension method.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to query against a Dictionary collection, you can do the following:

```
static class TestDictionary 
{
    static void Main() {
        Dictionary<int, string> numbers;
        numbers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        numbers.Add(0, "zero");
        numbers.Add(1, "one");
        numbers.Add(2, "two");
        numbers.Add(3, "three");
        numbers.Add(4, "four");

        var query =
          from n in numbers
          where (n.Value.StartsWith("t"))
          select n.Value;
    }
}
```

You can also use the n.Key property like so

```
var evenNumbers =
      from n in numbers
      where (n.Key % 2) == 0
      select n.Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var stringValue = dictionary[key];
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you do something like:

`var value = myDictionary[i];`?

Answer (score 3):

```
string value = dictionary[key];
```

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary.TryGetValue` is the safest way
or use Dictionary indexer as other suggested but remember to catch KeyNotFoundException

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not quite sure what you are asking here but i guess it's about a Dictionary?

It is quite easy to get the string value if you know the key.

```
string myValue = myDictionary[yourKey];
```

If you want to make use like an indexer (if this dictionary is in a class) you can use the following code.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary;

  public string this[string key]
  {
    get { return myDictionary[key]; }
  }
}
```